# (angularjs) getting 'ReferenceError: $scope is not defined' when injecting controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have am trying to learn AngularJS. I  have a HTML page where I am trying to inject module but getting an error

The main js file:

```
var classificationModule = angular.module('mainapp',[]);

classificationModule.controller('firstcontroll',function(){
    $scope.text="Goodday"
});
```

The **HTML** PAGE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title>Classification Toolkit for Grails</title>          

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js"></script>
    <asset:javascript src="main.js"/>        

</head>
<body >   
    <div ng-app='mainapp' ng-controller='firstcontroll'>
        Hello, {{text}}
    </div>   

</body>
</html>
```

Getting the following error :

```
ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Replace @scope with $scope. @ is not a valid javascript token

Comment: Did That. A new error occurs. Does there seem to be a problem with the way I am laoding angular JS ?

Answer (score 3):

Try passing `$scope` in the function.

```js
var classificationModule = angular.module('mainapp', []);

classificationModule.controller('firstcontroll', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "Goodday"
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="layout" content="main" />
  <title>Classification Toolkit for Grails</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js"></script>
  <asset:javascript src="main.js" />

</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app='mainapp' ng-controller='firstcontroll'>
    Hello, {{text}}
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```js
var classificationModule = angular.module('mainapp', []);

classificationModule.controller('firstcontroll', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "Goodday"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='mainapp' ng-controller='firstcontroll'>
  Hello, {{text}}
</div>
```

$scope is a variable provided by angular JS' dependency injection system, and basically it works by matching providers to named parameters.